# Possibilities to define if video card is dead?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card

Recently I've got this problem on my PC: when I turn it on, the screen works OK during bios/loading screen; as soon as the boot is complete, right before showing me desktop, the screen goes dark and monitor tells that "it is not connected". 
I knew that this problem could be caused by broken drivers, so I restarted my computer in safe mode, and the monitor worked. I've disabled the video card, restarted my computer, and was able to boot up normally with the resolution of about 800x600. I've tried installing the latest drivers, but the problem remains each time I try to restart the computer and enable the video card.

I've tried googling it and doing what other people say - with no luck. From what I understand, the only explanation could be that the video card is dead. However, there are 2 things that bother me: first of all, my monitor is plugged through that video card, and it works whenever I disable the video card driver; second, I can see the video card in my devices list. Is there any sort of test I can perform in order to determine if the card is really, 100% dead, and that it is definitely not the driver problem?

My system infos:
-Video card: nvidia quadro 600
-OS: dualboot windows 7 + ubuntu 14.04 (the problem remains on both systems)
 -I have another videocard embedded in my motherboard. I suppose, when I disable the first one, the monitor works from that embedded one

What have I tried in order to fix my problem (with no luck):
 -Reinstalling the drivers several times; I get my drivers from official NVIDIA website
 -Booting up in windows with a special low resolution mode (640x480)
Nothing has helped so far.

Comment: It displays BIOS, therefore is not 'dead'.

Comment: Could it be doing some kind of autodetection and getting it wrong? I remember similar problems way back when I was using the wrong resolution with my monitor. Are you able to enable the nvidia drivers but use low resolution and keep going up until you hit the right one? Also have you tried to disable the embedded on from BIOS in case it using that as the primary?